# Xcode framework no longer found after second build

Tags: c++, xcode, frameworks, xcode11

Since I upgraded to Xcode 11 every new project I start that includes a framework can be no longer be compiled after the second build of the project.

For example including SDL2 using this command:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

will result in this error:

```
'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found
```

after the project has been compiled a second time.

Projects that have been created in Xcode 10 work normal in Xcode 11. 
I tried changing the embedding options of the frameworks but no setting works. This error occurs in all Xcode 11 versions (0 - 2.1).
I am using macOS Version `10.14.6`.

**Why does this happen or how can this be fixed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I added the frameworks with the menu in this screenshot to my project:

[image]

In Xcode 9 and 10 this did the same as adding the framework using this menu:

[image]

But now in Xcode 11 this isn't the same anymore. Adding the framework using the first menu will copy the framework from it's original path into the build folder of the project but for some reason Xcode does **not** copy the `Headers` folder in the framework. I think this is a bug but it seems like they haven't fixed it up to Xcode version `11.2.1` at least.

So now the solution to this problem is adding the framework using the `Build Phases` menu in the second picture.

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same problem with XCode 11.1. What I found out was that I needed to add the Header Search Path in Build Settings/Search Paths to:

```
/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/Headers
```

And then it worked. It looks like the path is changed.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me, also this can't explain why the error only occurs after the first build.

Answer (score -1):

SDL2 isn't a framework. Rather it is either a static or dynamic lib. Unless of course you are using some other custom made framework for SDL2.

There are two scenarios you would typically encounter:

1. SDL2 installed in the default location such as /usr/local
2. SDL2 installed in a custom place (which is how I do it)

I am guessing you are doing the former. If this is the case, it is possible that with Xcode 11 the default system header search path has somehow changed to not include /usr/local (or where you have installed it).

To fix this, you should first locate your SDL2 library. In particular where the include files are.

Then in Build Settings, go to Search Paths:System Header Search Paths and enter that path in.

[image: Build Settings]

Keep in mind the `#include` is using `SDL2` as part of the path, so you do not want to put the `SDL2` part in the path. Here is an example of my directory structure. So my path entry for this is `$(PROJECT_DIR)/3rdParty/SDL2/include`. You can see in my project directory, I have a 3rdParty directory which I use to hold the 3rd Party libs I integrate into the project.

[image: Example directory structure]

You're using angled brackets for inclusion, which utilizes the system path.

Note you also may have to do update how you link against SDL2 (ie. it may not be able to find it).

Comment: I don't know how you installed SDL, but the default way since version 2.0.8 is a real `.framework` file, placed into `/Library/Frameworks/`. And also this is how I did it. All my static libraries still work fine, it is just frameworks that don't work. Also the strange thing is that it only happens after the first build but not in the first build.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'm using 2.0.10. I built it from source. I typically build 3rd party when I can and in the SDL2 case, it's quite easy to do. I don't think there is a net advantage to using a framework in this case. You can try adjusting the System Framework Search Paths to where the framework is. Obviously you'd be setting it to explicitly to /Library/Frameworks, but at least you could check that off your list of things you looked into.

Comment: I really prefer Frameworks and I always use them. With them the libraries on Mac are already handled. The path is already set so this can't be the problem.